# Difference between JExcelApiExporter and JRXlsExporter

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, apache-poi, jxl

I am using JasperReports to create report in .xls format. I found that there are similar classes `JExcelApiExporter` and `JRXlsExporter` with almost same functionality.

Is there any difference between these two classes? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both can export to excel format, however their implementations are completely different:

- `JExcelApiExporter` uses [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) who says is a "Java API to read, write,
  and modify Excel spreadsheets";
- `JRXlsExporter` uses [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) who says is "the
  Java API for Microsoft Documents".

These APIs have similarities and differences ([see this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986986/2245051)). You should consider your needs and try them both to decide for yourself. For example, I conducted one experiment and one of the .xls had less bytes than the other and had a different color on a field (blue vs gray)...