# How to write a programme to Read from an excel sheet , write from an excel sheet in java

Tags: java

How to write a program to Read from an excel sheet , write from an excel sheet in java.  By creating   columns like

> name, age,gender, salary, designation.

```
if ( sal > 5000)
 then update as fresher

if (sal >5000 and < 40000)

then it is lead

if (sal >40000 and <60000)
```

then it is manager.

Comment: Since you have a badge that indicates that you have gone through the [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you should know that this question is not something that you should ask here. Please read further through the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check out this post :

[What is the better API to Reading Excel sheets in java - JXL or Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980717/what-is-the-better-api-to-reading-excel-sheets-in-java-jxl-or-apache-poi)

It will give you enough informations to get started.

---

You can also give a try to search about CSV format, which can be imported and exported from Excel

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but as far as I understand it you probably want something like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Using below link you can get the both code for read or write data into Excel

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: Thanks Diyar,alexandre,shiladittya for ur replies

Comment: Feel free to upvote / accept this answer if it helped you.